# Execute functional interface as lambda

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I'm not sure if the title really suits what I want to convey. Let me explain it with an example:

```
public static void test() {
    Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
    c.accept("hello world");
}
```

I want to know if there is a more "sophisticated" way of executing a functional interface, something like `c("hello world")`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, there is not.

Comment: I mean, the nicer way to execute the example you've given here would be `System.out.println("hello world");`, right? Is there maybe a more realistic example you can show to demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I think the example itself is not meaningful, my question is if there is any way of executing a lamba expression stored in some functional interface variable without the need of calling the specific method of that funcional interface. The code is just an example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Once again: no.

Comment: Despite all the syntactic magic, functions still aren't first class objects in Java, all your variables still store references to actual Java objects. That is not to say the same effect couldn't be achieved with even more syntactic sugar, just that maybe it would obscure the reality of what is happening a bit too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Java was not originally designed to be a functional language, so the modern functional features of Java unfortunately feel a bit "bolted-on". On the other hand, some of the more modern languages, such as Kotlin (or slightly less modern ones such as Scala), *do* allow you to call a functional interface (or equivalent in that language) as if it were a simple method.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. You call it by calling method as in your example.